# Aliasing on Clang for OSX

Tags: c, macos, clang

I'm working on getting some code to compile on OSX that's been pretty Linux focused for a while. One of the pieces involves using a variable alias that doesn't seem to translate well:

```
extern type1_t var_name __attribute__((alias("var_name_")));
extern type2_t var_name2[SIZE_MACRO] __attribute__((alias("var_name2_")));
```

When I compile this on my Mac with `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)`, I get this output:

```
filename.c:81:66: error: only weak aliases are supported on darwin
extern type1_t var_name __attribute__((alias("var_name_")));
                                       ^
filename.c:82:92: error: only weak aliases are supported on darwin
extern type2_t var_name2[SIZE_MACRO] __attribute__((alias("var_name2_")));
                                                    ^
```

So I figured I needed to make these weak symbols by adding `weak,` to the definition, but I get the same result:

```
filename.c:81:66: error: only weak aliases are supported on darwin
extern type1_t var_name __attribute__((weak,alias("var_name_")));
                                       ^
filename.c:82:92: error: only weak aliases are supported on darwin
extern type2_t var_name2[SIZE_MACRO] __attribute__((weak,alias("var_name2_")));
                                                    ^
```

Based on research from the web, if I move to GCC, that will clear things up for this particular problem, but I need this to be able to compile cleanly for Macs on all compilers, including Clang. What do I need to do here to make this work?

Comment: `__attribute__` is not standard C, thus not portable by definition. Additionally, weak symbols require the object file format support it. Thus you have a portability issue anyway. Maybe there is a standard compliant way to achieve what you want. At least you should use macros to encapsulate the `__attribute__` syntax.